# DOM elements as model properties in BackboneJS

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js

I am making something similar to this:

http://orange.blender.org/wp-content/themes/orange/images/blog/noodles.jpg

My NodeGraph model consists of Nodes and Connections. My Connection model contains FromNode, FromProperty and ToNode, ToProperty. When drawing the connection, I want to find the associated DOM element for the "dot". The problem is that this is a View-dependent property (and may even differ between browsers). Should I send this info FROM the view back to the model? Or should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure I don't completely understand your question, but here's a short answer.

Create your Node and Connection models as pure models without any View references.  These models will have both an id and a cid property.  The cid is assigned by backbone.js.  The id would be assigned by your server.  Given the presence of these properties, you now have identity for these models.

Now in your view(s), you can use either one of id or cid as DOM ids—you may use these as the id or you may need to use them as a component of a DOM id (e.g. 'connect-24').

Comment: Thanks Bill. I've added a method to my Connection model getDOMid()